# AutoMapper: Keep Destination Value if the property doesnt exists in source

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, automapper, asp.net-identity-2

I tried to search a lot, and try different options but nothing seems to work.

I am using ASP.net Identity 2.0 and I have UpdateProfileViewModel . When Updating the User info, I want to map the UpdateProfileViewModel to ApplicationUser (i.e. the Identity Model); but I want to keep the values, I got from the db for the user. i.e. the Username & Email address, that doesn't needs to change.

I tried doing :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UpdateProfileViewModel, ApplicationUser>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Email, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

but I still get the Email as null after mapping:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
user = Mapper.Map<UpdateProfileViewModel, ApplicationUser>(model);
```

I also tried this but doesn't works:

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreAllNonExisting<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
    {
        var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
        var destinationType = typeof(TDestination);
        var existingMaps = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().First(x => x.SourceType.Equals(sourceType) && x.DestinationType.Equals(destinationType));
        foreach (var property in existingMaps.GetUnmappedPropertyNames())
        {
            expression.ForMember(property, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
        return expression;
    }
```

and then:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<UpdateProfileViewModel, ApplicationUser>()
.IgnoreAllNonExisting();
```

Comment: Try "UseDestinationValue" instead  of "Ignore"

Comment: It still remains null in the user object.

Comment: For AutoMapper 11+, use `CreateMap<>(MemberList.None)` or `CreateMap<>(MemberList.Source)` to select the list of fields to map, instead of `.IgnoreAllExisting()` or `.ForAllOtherMembers()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need is to create a mapping between your source and destination types:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UpdateProfileViewModel, ApplicationUser>();
```

and then perform the mapping:

```
UpdateProfileViewModel viewModel = ... this comes from your view, probably bound
ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
Mapper.Map(viewModel, user);

// at this stage the user domain model will only have the properties present
// in the view model updated. All the other properties will remain unchanged
// You could now go ahead and persist the updated 'user' domain model in your
// datastore
```

Comment: It will copy them assuming you have the same property names and types in your domain model.

Comment: Then I suppose you are doing something wrong and not the way I showed in my answer. The `Mapper.Map` method, **as shown in my answer**, will copy all property values present in the source object into the destination object without affecting any other properties in the dest object.

Comment: You are Right. I am sorry. I didn't notice, that I should remove the <UpdateProfileViewModel, ApplicationUser> from the Map method.

Thanks a lotttttt. I deleted my comments, so any future user isn't misguided.

Answer (score 0):

Mapper will return a new object when assigned to the destination object, instead you must use Map to pass the source and destination as parameters.

```
public class SourceObjectModel 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationObjectModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

SourceObjectModel sourceObj = new SourceObjectModel() {Name = "foo"};
DestinationObjectModel destinObj = new DestinationObjectModel(){Id = 1};


/*update only "name" in destinObj*/
_mapper.Map<SourceObjectModel, DestinationObjectModel>(sourceObj, destinObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do :

```
Mapper.Map(model, user);
```

instead of :

```
user = Mapper.Map<UpdateProfileViewModel, ApplicationUser>(model);
```